# Doctrain ZF2 : Can not able to save data for oneToMany Relation

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I can not able to save data into tables using oneTomany relation in doctrain2 and ZF2.

it giving the MySQL foreign key null error.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO phv_image (path, name, suggestion_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["test.png", "test", null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'suggestion_id' cannot be null
```

My Code is

**1 Entity**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PhvImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="phv_image", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="suggestion_id", columns={"suggestion_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PhvImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \PhvSuggestion
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhvSuggestion", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="suggestion_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $suggestion;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return PhvImage
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return PhvImage
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set suggestion
     *
     * @param \PhvSuggestion $suggestion
     *
     * @return PhvImage
     */
    public function setSuggestion(\Application\Entity\PhvSuggestion $suggestion = null)
    {
        $this->suggestion = $suggestion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get suggestion
     *
     * @return \PhvSuggestion
     */
    public function getSuggestion()
    {
        return $this->suggestion;
    }
}
```

**2 Entity**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * PhvSuggestion
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="phv_suggestion", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PhvSuggestion extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subject", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $subject;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;
    /**
     * @var \PhvUser
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhvUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PhvImage", mappedBy="suggestion", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    public $images;
    private $data = null;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set subject
     *
     * @param string $subject
     *
     * @return PhvSuggestion
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get subject
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->subject;
    }
    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return PhvSuggestion
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \PhvUser $user
     *
     * @return PhvSuggestion
     */
    public function setUser(PhvUser $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \PhvUser
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function setImages($images){
        $this->images = $images;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getImages() {
        return $this->images;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function saveAction() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
        $imgObj = new \Application\Entity\PhvImage();
        $imgObj->setPath('test.png');
        $imgObj->setName('test');

        $imgObj2 = new \Application\Entity\PhvImage();
        $imgObj2->setPath('new.png');
        $imgObj2->setName('new');

        $arr = array(
                $imgObj,$imgObj2
        );

    $sugg = new \Application\Entity\PhvSuggestion();
$sugg->setUser(1);
$sugg->setImages($arr);
 $sugg->setDescription('test');
            $sugg->setSubject('sub');
            $em->persist($sugg);
            $em->flush();

    }
```

Can you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in the Class `PhvSuggestion` you need to add a constructor as the following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->images = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then change `setImages` to:

```
public function addImages(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $images)
{
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image->setSuggestion($this);
        $this->images->add($image);
    }
}
```

You can find all of these details in the Doctrine 2 documentation.

Comment: I can not able to solve this issue using above solution. in that images are not getting saved into the table only the suggestion get save.